# Finding the integer parts of irrationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation

When working with continued fraction expansions, I sometimes have to calculate the integer part of irrationals quickly without a calculator, what would be an effective way to do this?

For example, how would one quickly and accurately find the integer part of:

i) $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{5}$

ii) $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{11}$

iii) $\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{13}$

iv) $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{11}+3)$

I can only use working out on paper and I would like a consistent method to use for an upcoming test

Example: for $\sqrt{11}$ I know that $11$ is between $9$ and $16$ so the integer part would clearly be $3$

The same method cannot be as easily applied for when we are working with a fraction of this irrational

Comment: I remember an approximate to find squareroot of any small number though not for sure. You can Find square of 11 like this 

Find nearest smaller and largest square number , 9 ,16 

Then $\sqrt{11}=\sqrt{9}+\frac{11-9}{16-9}$ gives an ok approximate. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method works for your examples :

$$2\lt\sqrt 5\lt 3\Rightarrow 0\lt\frac 23\lt\frac{\sqrt 5}{3}\lt \frac 33=1$$
$$3\lt \sqrt{11}\lt 4\Rightarrow 0\lt \frac 34\lt\frac{\sqrt{11}}{4}\lt\frac 44=1$$
$$3\lt\sqrt{13}\lt 4\Rightarrow 0\lt\frac 38\lt\frac{\sqrt{13}}{8}\lt \frac 48\lt 1$$
$$3\lt\sqrt{11}\lt 4\Rightarrow 6\lt\sqrt{11}+3\lt 7\Rightarrow 3\lt\frac{\sqrt{11}+3}{2}\lt\frac 72=3.5$$